# CSV to SQL import reorders the CSV Data Haphazardly WHY?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, csv

When I try to import CSV file to my sql server table. The row data automatically reorders itself. why?

schema for my sql table is :

create table ZCPTble(
EmployeeID INT , 
EmployeeName NVARCHAR(255) ,
ProjectID NVARCHAR(255),
WBSElement NVARCHAR(255),
AllocationPercent FLOAT,
ProjSBUName NVARCHAR(255),
ProjectPractice NVARCHAR(255),
ProjectProfile NVARCHAR(255),
ProjectManagerID INT,
ProjectManager NVARCHAR(255),
DeliveryManagerID INT,
DeliveryManager NVARCHAR(255),
SupervisorID INT,
Supervisor NVARCHAR(255),

EmployeeStatus NVARCHAR(255),
BusinessLead NVARCHAR(255),
BusinessLeadName NVARCHAR(255)
)

```
import glob
import os
import csv
import pyodbc
import time
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


def trim(dataset):
    trim = lambda x: x.strip() if type(x) is str else x
    return dataset.applymap(trim)


conn1 = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};'
                       r'Server=XXX\SQLSERVER2017;'
                       r'Database=ABC;'
                       r'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cur1 = conn1.cursor()

start = time.time()

# Names of all columns

list_of_column_names = {
                        'EmployeeID',
                        'EmployeeName',
                        'ProjectID',

                        'WBSElement',
                        'AllocationPercent',
                        'ProjSBUName',

                        'ProjectPractice',
                        'ProjectProfile',


                        'ProjectManagerID',
                        'ProjectManager',

                        'DeliveryManagerID',
                        'DeliveryManager',

                        'SupervisorID',
                        'Supervisor',

                        'EmployeeStatus',
                        'BusinessLead',
                        'BusinessLeadName'

                        }
print(len(list_of_column_names))

df = pd.DataFrame()

# impoting newest csv file
list_of_files = glob.glob(
    'C://Users/ABX/SDD/ASY/Sample/*')  # * means all if need specific format then *.csv
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)

for files in os.listdir("C://Users/ABX/SDD/ASY/Sample/"):
    print(files)
    with open(latest_file, "r") as file:
        df = pd.read_csv(file)

        df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='Unnamed: ')))]

        # Rename all columns
        df.columns = list_of_column_names
        #converting all numeric to numeric type
        try:
            for col in ['EmployeeID', 'AllocationPercent', 'SupervisorID', 'ProjectManagerID', 'DeliveryManagerID']:
                df[col] = df[col].apply(pd.to_numeric)
        except KeyError:
            continue

#writing to sql server

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=XXX1\SQLSERVER2017;DATABASE=ABC;Trusted_Connection=yes')
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)

engine = create_engine(conn_str)
df.to_sql(name='ProjectAllocationDetails', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

print("The Data was inserted succesfully.")

end = time.time()

# release memory from the dataframe
del df
print(end - start)
```

Data shifts haphazardly. For examples, Employee ID column of sql table has Employee Name instead Date column gets the name instead .Why so?

Comment: This problem often arise when there are issues in the CSV file. Can you post a sample? Have you tried to print the content of `df`, after `df = pd.read_csv(file)` ?

Comment: Moreover, you have written "The row data automatically reorders", but this is not the issue, am I right? the problem is on *columns* order

Comment: Yes I printed the content of the df. While I was debugging thats when I realised, what the bug was. Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: The issue is solved. A minor bug in the code. The variable list_of_column_names is supposed to be a list object. The brackets used in the code are wrong.

Comment: Ah! Yes, that's not a minor bug. You defined a set instead of a list, that's why columns are completely scrambled.